# Xcode Firebase not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error on xCode. Where is the problem ? I have cleaned my project, builded and installed pods again. But I could not fix my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding (links to) screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: see you pod file